# HTML creating <a href...> with style

Tags: html, css, href

I've created a link that looks like a button like this:

```
<a target='_blank' href="mailto:me@myemail.com?Subject=bla bla" style='background:#44ff22;color:#ffffff;font-size:15px;padding:8px 12px;border-radius:3px;-moz-border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;text-decoration:none;'>Email Me</a>
```

the problem is that the clickable area is not the entire box (it's on the top third portion of the "button") so one might think its not working

How can I create the clickable rectangle area?

Comment: Can you post fiddle of your code?

Comment: Putting bare `mailto:` links is not good practice. The email address might be harvested by spambots that crawl the web looking for email addresses.

Comment: @Ihazkode you are correct, but that's not the issue I'm trying to solve at the moment ;)

Answer (score 2):

Why bother? Just put your tags around a button

```
<a><button></button></a>
```

Comment: and if you need you can always modify looks of your button

Comment: Why to add additional elements when things can be achieved with simple CSS?

Comment: @KalpeshPatel Yes - because HTML elements were not made to be used - you should replace them with 10 lines of css code that will do the same

Comment: I've tried this option too and it didn't work at all = 0 clickable area: `<button onclick="location.href='mailto:me@myemail.com?Subject=bla bla' style='background:#44ff22;color:#ffffff;font-size:15px;padding:8px 12px;border-radius:3px;-moz-border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;text-decoration:none;'>Email Me</button>`

Comment: @KukulaMula put button in "a" tags and add attributes only to "a" tag

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: block` or `display: inline-block` property to your style.

```css
a {
  background:#44ff22;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-size:15px;
  padding:8px 12px;
  border-radius:3px;
  -moz-border-radius:3px;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;
  text-decoration:none;
  
  display: block; /* Added */
}
```

```html
<a target='_blank' href="mailto:me@myemail.com?Subject=bla bla">Email Me</a>
```

```css
a {
  background:#44ff22;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-size:15px;
  padding:8px 12px;
  border-radius:3px;
  -moz-border-radius:3px;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;
  text-decoration:none;
  
  display: inline-block; /* Added */
}
```

```html
<a target='_blank' href="mailto:me@myemail.com?Subject=bla bla">Email Me</a>
```

Comment: I did it made no change, clickable area stayed the same (I also cleaned the cache to be sure its reloading fresh)